# jQuery - How to run effect of 0.5 sec later

Tags: jquery

how to run effect of 0.5 sec later ? I need to delay the effect of driving away when the mouse to 0.5 sec (mouseleave).

[Live Demo](http://kod.djpw.cz/lgfb)

someone please help? :-( Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `setTimeout()` method, like this:

```
setTimeout(500, function() {
    codeThatIWantToRunAfter500ms();
});
```

Check here for more info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: And where exactly do I paste? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can put in this

```
$(document).on({
        mouseenter: flip,
        mouseleave: function(e) {setTimeout(function(){flip.call(e.currentTarget, e);}, 500);},
    }, '.flip')
});
```

See working fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/ety4vjdu/